# Trying to understand Generic List in C#

Tags: c#, object, generics

I hope everyone is well.

I have some practice code here that I've been working on and the code works and I have no issues with it however, I don't find that I fully understand what I've written and why it works.

I want to try and be able to understand my work so that I can become a better programmer, I've left comments for the code that I dont fully understand, the rest I am comfortable with.

I would appreciate any one with the spare time to give me a few pointers and some help, thank you very much.

```
namespace GenericList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* I understand how objects work, but I dont fully understand 
               what is happening when I am passig through my constructer
               name through the List */
            List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>();

            /* I am passing matching arguments through each instance 
               of my cities List object but I still struggle to 
               visualise this process */
            cities.Add(new Cities(1, "Durban - Home to the largest harbor in Africa"));
            cities.Add(new Cities(2, "Johannesburg - The largest city in the country"));
            cities.Add(new Cities(3, "Gqebetha - Also known as P.E, the friendly city"));
            cities.Add(new Cities(4, "Bloemfontien - Host of the Rose Festival"));
            cities.Add(new Cities(5, "Pretoria - South Africa's capital"));



            Console.WriteLine("Which city would you like to know an interesting fact for?" +
                "\n1) Durban" +
                "\n2) Johannesburg" +
                "\n3) Gqebetha" +
                "\n4) Bloemfontien" +
                "\n5) Pretoria" +
                "\nEnter the number for the city you want:");
                int answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            bool found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < cities.Count; i++)
            {
                if (cities[i].Id.Equals(answer))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nANSWER: " + cities[i].City);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nWe couldn't find what you are looking for.");
            }
        }
    }

    class Cities
    {
        int id;
        string city;

        public Cities(int id, string city)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.city = city;
        }

        public int Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
        public string City { get => city; set => city = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may get more feedback posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: a `List<Cities>` stores a list of instances of your `Cities` class (that really should be called 'City' as it describes just one). You cannot store a string or a "Person" there - for that you would need a `List<string>` or `List<Person>`. See [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)

Comment: First I suggest to name the class in singular manner.

Comment: I think you really need to go back to some basics here and understand some core concepts. First of all, generics seem to be your problem. You use the word "constructor" when I think you actually mean the *generic type parameter*.

Comment: A list is like a shelf, storing boxes side-by-side in a row. Your `City` class (it's a _single_ city, not a bunch of cities, remove the plural please) is like one such box. The box contains a number and a name. These 'boxes' are added to the list, which places them side-by-side like boxes on a shelf.

Comment: Thank you all very much. This highlights a bit of basic logic and terminology that I've missed or have forgotten. The class being plural I now understand why isn't correct, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>();`

Here you are creating a List, which contains only the object of Cities's class.

- List is a array type data structure with various utilities(method).
- Here you are using `Add()`, which append a new object to the list (in that case only Cities object as you declare in first line `List<Cities>`).
- `cities.Add(new Cities(1, "Durban - Home to the largest harbor in Africa"));`
  If I break down this line this will be:

```
// Creating a new Cities object
var newCity = new Cities(1, "Durban - Home to the largest harbor in Africa");

cities.Add(newCity );
```

Last line from the code block is appending `newCity` to the list of `cities`

*Hope you understand now, If anything left unclear let me know*

Comment: Thank you, Bin Rohan.

Answer (score 2):

i rewrote with linq so you can see as a different approach. more easy reading code

```
void Main()
{
    List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>();

    //add to cities array a new City class, since constructor accept 2 parameters you supply them on new object creation
    Cities city;
    city = new Cities(1, "Durban - Home to the largest harbor in Africa");
    cities.Add(city);
    city = new Cities(2, "Johannesburg - The largest city in the country");
    cities.Add(city);
    city = new Cities(3, "Gqebetha - Also known as P.E, the friendly city");
    cities.Add(city);
    city = new Cities(4, "Bloemfontien - Host of the Rose Festival");
    cities.Add(city);
    city = new Cities(5, "Pretoria - South Africa's capital");
    cities.Add(city);

    //different approach: create list with objects
    cities = new List<Cities>()
    {
        new Cities(1, "Durban - Home to the largest harbor in Africa"),
        new Cities(2, "Johannesburg - The largest city in the country"),
        new Cities(3, "Gqebetha - Also known as P.E, the friendly city"),
        new Cities(4, "Bloemfontien - Host of the Rose Festival"),
        new Cities(5, "Pretoria - South Africa's capital")
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Which city would you like to know an interesting fact for?" +
        "\n1) Durban" +
        "\n2) Johannesburg" +
        "\n3) Gqebetha" +
        "\n4) Bloemfontien" +
        "\n5) Pretoria" +
        "\nEnter the number for the city you want:");
    int answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var result = cities
        .Select((obj, index) => new { index, obj }) //set index for each object
        .Where(w => w.index == answer)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (result == null)
        Console.WriteLine("\nWe couldn't find what you are looking for.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\nANSWER: " + result.obj.City);
}


class Cities
{
    //class properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    //Parameterized Constructor     https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-constructors-with-examples#divcspzcst
    public Cities(int id, string city)
    {
        Id = id;
        City = city;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you at, @Power Mouse. This is very insightful, I have a lot here that I can learn on.

Comment: if you need, you can add an empty constructor, in case you want to add values to object after object creation. so you can add to class an empty constructor.
 public Cities(){}

Answer (score 1):

With

```
List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>();
```

you create a new List-object that can store `Cities` objects. The generic type parameter `<Cities>` denotes the type of the list items and does not refer to the constructor. As an example, the following code would create a list that could store integer values:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
```

The `List<T>` class is a generic type. The basic operations for a list like adding, removing, enumerating and so on are the same no matter what the type of the list items is. By creating a generic type, you can implement the functionality without knowing which types are used later on when you create an object. You might compare this to a method: when you implement the method, you define the parameters and their types; when you call the method, you supply the values of the parameters.

The code in the following line performs two tasks:

```
cities.Add(new Cities(1, "Durban - Home to the largest harbor in Africa"));
```

First, a new object of type `Cities` is created and initialized through the constructor. Second, it is added to the list. These are two separate steps that   can also written like this:

```
// Create new object of type Cities
var city = new Cities(1, "Durban - Home to the largest harbor in Africa");
// Add newly created object to list
cities.Add(city);
```

As @BinRohan suggested in the comments, it might be a good idea the rename the `Cities` class to `City` because it defines a single city, not a collection of cities.

Comment: Thank you, Markus, this is a big help. I had a lot of confusion over the list type parameter and It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

When you write this line of code

```
  List<Cities> cities = new List<Cities>();
```

You instantiate an object being a List of "Cities". List is a "generic" type. It means it is able to handle any type and will behave the same. You could have a List or List, you'll manipulate different objects but the behaviour of List remains the same. You are not "passing" Cities to the List constructor, consider List as a type in itself.
It would be equivalent of declaring an array of Cities for example. There is no data in your list yet but it is ready to receive multiple instance of Cities.

Then when you write

```
cities.Add(New Cities{prop1=value,prop2=value...});
```

at run time it will do something like

```
var c = new Cities();
c.prop1=value;
c.prop2=value;
cities.Add(c);
```

It's kind of a shortcut which also make the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @Cyril ANDRE. I will definitely start implementing this from now on.